# Remove trailing zeros from DateTime.Now.Date

Tags: c#

I would like to write some information to log files. First I want to write down the date, then the time and after that the log message. An example would be

> 11.02.2019 | 09:36:24 | Something finished

Currently I get logged this

```
11.02.2019 00:00:00 | 09:36:24 | ...
11.02.2019 00:00:00 | 09:36:24 | ...
11.02.2019 00:00:00 | 09:36:24 | ...
```

I use this code for the date and time handling

```
private string GetDateTimestamp()
{
    string currentDate = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString();
    string currentTime = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    return $"{currentDate} | {currentTime} | ";
}
```

How can I remove the trailing zeros from the date when using `c# DateTime.Now.Date`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ToShortDateString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.toshortdatestring?view=netframework-4.7.2). In addition, you don't need to use the `Date` property:

```
string currentDate = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
```

As an alternative, you can specify the DateTime format also like this (*d* for short date format, *T* for long time format):

```
private string GetDateTimestamp()
{
    var dtNow = DateTime.Now;
    return $"{dtNow:d} | {dtNow:T} | ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Same way you filtered out the date from your `currentTime`

```
string currentDate = DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString();
```

Additional you could also make use of the `ToString()` [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) to provide your own format and do it all in 1 step:

```
var result = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd | HH:mm:ss | ");
```